# Removing highlighting when mouse changes direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, highlight, drag

I am trying to develop a customizable schedule web app.

What I am after is essentially the normal highlighting behaviour you get when you click and drag to highlight text, but I want this to work for table data elements. Like in Excel, if you click and drag to highlight cells but then reverse your mouse direction, it will un-highlight cells that you "back-tracked" over.

Is it possible to do this using jQuery?

So far I can 'highlight' cells but I can't figure out how to control the un-highlighting without un-highlighting everything the mouse leaves. I've been researching a solution for quite a while with no success.

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="control-panel">
    <button onclick="addAppt()" id="add-appt" title="Add Appointment">+  </button>
    <p>= Add Appointment</p>
    <button onclick="delAppt()" id="del-appt" title="Delete Appointment">-</button>
    <p>= Delete Appointment</p>
</div>

<table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="days-of-the-week">
          <th scope="col" class="time-col"></th>
          <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
          <th scope="col">Monday</th>
          <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
          <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
          <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
          <th scope="col">Friday</th>
          <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">7:30 AM</th>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">8:00 AM</th>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">8:30 AM</th>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">9:00 AM</th>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
          <td rowspan=""><textarea cols="20" rows="5" class="appt-text"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  font-family: Arvo, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-top: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-left: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.days-of-the-week th {
  width: 160px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

tr td, th {
  border-right: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4DC7E8;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
}

.days-of-the-week .time-col {
  width: 80px;
}

tbody th {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 3px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: rgba(255, 108, 78, 0.3); 
}

.appt-text {
   background-color: inherit;
   border: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   outline: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function addAppt() {
$('td').css('cursor', 'cell');
$('textarea').css('cursor', 'cell');
var spanCount = 1; 
$('td').mousedown(function(){
      $('td').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
      });
    });
    $('td').mouseup(function(){
      $('td').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });
}

function delAppt() {
    $('td').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
    $('textarea').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
    $('td').click(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
    $('td').mousedown(function(){
      $('td').hover(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      });
    });
    $('td').mouseup(function(){
      $('td').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });
}
```

EDIT: I added a jsfiddle to see if this can get more attention.

https://jsfiddle.net/Adam_M/fypw7jka/

I learned how to code only about 2 months ago, so I apologize if this code looks inefficient/bad. I am open to other suggestions/techniques if an explanation is provided!

Comment: Instead of `$(this).addClass('highlight');` try `$(this).toggleClass('highlight');`

Comment: @imtheman toggleClass works for unhighlighting the cell once the cursor leaves the cell, but it does this for every cell I hover over, including the ones in the middle of my drag range. So I end up with one cell highlighted where I clicked, and then another one highlighted wherever my cursor is, but all cells in between are also de-highlighted.